# Get contents of json file not working

Tags: json, angular, angular2-http

I want to get a json object from a json file using angular 2 `http.get`. What I end up getting from the file is this:

```
t_isScalar: falseoperator: tsource: t__proto__: Object
```

Here is my code

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidateJSONSchemaService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getSchema(fileName): any {
        return(this.http.get(fileName)
            .map(this.extractData)
        );
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }
}
```

How do I fix `getSchema` to make it return the json object rather than this: `t_isScalar: falseoperator: tsource: t__proto__: Object`. Note that when I change the file name it returns the same thing. I would have expected an informational error (I did do error handling but the code never errors out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidateJSONSchemaService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getSchema(fileName): any {
        return(this.http.get(fileName)
            .map(this.extractData).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
        );
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Maciej s answer you can use the `| async` pipe that does the subscribing for you.

```
<div>{{getSchmea('fileName') | async}}</div>
```